# Rounding to midpoint of decimal place using ToString only

Tags: c#, rounding, tostring, displayformat

I know that `C#` has some options to format decimal numbers with some extended logic in the `ToString()` method, as e.g.

```
double d1 = 1.3333;
double d2 = 1.6666;
string d1Str = d1.ToString("#0.00"); // 1.33
string d2Str = d2.ToString("#0.00"); // 1.67
```

That's great, my number is rounded to the second decimal. But what if I wanted to round to a step of `0.05` instead of `0.01`? Is there a way to use the `ToString()` method in a similar way to round the value not to a given step-size (e.g. `0.05`)?

**Note:** I know I could do something like this:

```
(Math.Round(1.33333*20)/20).ToString();
```

but the question is about getting this result using `ToString()` only.

Comment: ToString() is about formatting values as strings, not performing calculations on them. Why do you want this in ToString()? Can't you create an extension method?

Comment: So I guess from your comment that your answer is "Not possible"? I "want" `ToString` because I have components allowing me to format output via the `ToString` method and nothing else.

Comment: @CodeCaster `.ToString()` already has the ability to round values for display. OP simply wants to round in an unorthodox way. I don't see where OP is trying to use `.ToString()` for calculations.

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types i didn't found any possibility to do with only existing format types. But you could override the `ToString` method and implement a custom format, but there you also have to round it with calculations instead a pure `ToString` solution

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to create an extension overload for `ToString()` for these components?

If so you could write something like:

```
public static class DoubleStaticExtension
{
    public static string ToString(this double value, string format, int decimalToRoundHalfwayAt)
    {
        int modifier = 2 * (int)Math.Pow(10, decimalToRoundHalfwayAt -1 );
        return (Math.Round(value * modifier, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / modifier).ToString(format);
    }
}
```

Calling that with

```
        double d = 9.333333;
        string result = d.ToString("#0.00", 2);
```

Would give a result of 9.35

And

```
    double d = 9.333333;
    string result = d.ToString("#0.00", 1);
```

Would give a result of 9.50